# Scrumptious Friday Meal

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

It's Friday - or *Friyay*! :) and I am sitting at a restaurant with my wife waiting for our order. . Can you tell me what have we ordered?
[image: waiting...]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have ordered:

> **NACHOS** and **COFFE(e)**

How to tell?

> By clicking on the image we are presented with another picture which shows two lists of number sequences written on a card:
>
>  87, 55, 37, 19, ...
>  10, 9, 8, 7, ...
>  11, 3, ...
>  49, 32, 15, ...
>  2, 9, ...
>
>  109, 77, 45, ...
>  5, 6, 7, 8, ...
>  105, 74, 43, ...
>
>  In each case we need to find out what comes next in each sequence. However, whilst some are simple (e.g. 5, 6, 7, 8 is followed by 9) not all of them are straightforward arithmetic progressions (e.g. 87, 55, 37, 19, ...).

However, we need to visualise these differently:

> As *atomic numbers*, on a Periodic *Table*! (The dining *table* is a clue by word association, and all numbers used fall conveniently in the range 1-118...)
>
>  [image: Augmented Periodic Table]
>
>  Once we do that we can see that all of the sequences appear as straight horizontal, vertical or diagonal lines, and we can then simply extend the lines to find the next element in the sequence.
>
>  Using the chemical symbols for these elements then yields **Na, C, H, O, S** and **Co, F, Fe** - in other words, you are ordering **NACHOS** and **COFFEE**! (There is unfortunately no element represented simple by 'E' to complete the word fully - this is as close as you'll get!)

Comment: What's the significance of the piece of paper on the table?

Comment: @samm82 Pretty sure that's rot13(jung lbh frr va zber qrgnvy jura lbh pyvpx ba gur cvpgher)

Comment: Ah, of course lol

Comment: While I drafted this some time back, I posted this from the restaurant :) And, well it was solved within minutes :D Great work @Stiv Bon App :)

Comment: @Techidiot, fine dining nachos and coffee, nice 